# Dropdown Bootstrap, conflict well z-index

Tags: z-index

I have a stupid problem, I created a well with media-list, I found that there is problem only with z-index, What is wrong?

[image]

Class dropdown-menu:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1001 !important;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that the well has explicitly set position relative on it, this way your dropdown-menu will be positioned relatively to it. Also try to set position on  .dropdown-menu class before Z-index.